# Can't inject UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have off the shelf app framework.  `Index.html` contains this

```
<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- MetsiMenu -->
<script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<!-- Peace JS -->
<script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
<script src="js/inspinia.js"></script>

<!-- Main Angular scripts-->
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Our application's scripts -->
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

and in `js/controllers.js`, I have

```
angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

and my controller is

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $interval, $state, $location)
```

when I try to inject UI bootstrap by chaning it to

```
.module('inspinia', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

I get

> "Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%24state%20%3C-%20MainCtrl

I am sure that it is something very simple, but I can't see what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using `$state` API service inside your controller so you also need to also include `ui.router` with it.

So while asking for `$state` dependency, injector doesn't able to find asked dependency inside angular DI container `$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider` in `MainCtrl`

```
angular
  .module('inspinia', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router'])
```

Comment: Thansk (+1). Strange, because I was successfllty changing state before, withough injectin ``ui.router. WHen I make your change, the error goes away, but no the HTMLno longer displays, and there are no erros in the debug console. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mawg does `inspinia` is your main module? which is used of `ng-app`?

Comment: If is pure JS. `$(document).ready(function ` it sts menu height & sidebar width by directly manipulating the DOM (ick!). If I comment it out, it makes no difference

Comment: @Mawg are you really using `ui-router` states.. are you using it inside your application? if yes then in which file they belongs?

Comment: yes. Sorry, I had posted form acut down project I was using to denug. I have updated the question to show `function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $interval, $state, $location)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107408/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-mawg).

Comment: I think, instead, that I will post a new uestion. I was only trying to inject ùi.bootstrap`because I hiought I needed it for `datepicker`, but Igot that  working in a small demo project withoutinjecting ùi.bootstrap`. Thanks extremely much for your help

Comment: @Mawg no problem, that happens. Glad to help you :)